# Good way to pass value into a function without passing it directly as parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have kotlin class which is Spring managed (it is a @Service). It calls a function on an object which isn't Spring managed. How to to pass a value to that function?

I don't want to just pass argument to it as this function is polymorphic and I only want one version of this function to use this value, other versions of this function don't need this value.

I get this value from properties file by using @Value annotation.

Code examples:

```
@Service
class ServiceClass(
    private val transactionTemplate: TransactionTemplate,
    @Value("\${some-value}")
    private val someValue: String
) {
    private fun callingPolymorphicFunction(polymorphicObjects: List<PolymorphicObjects>) {
        transactionTemplate.execute {
            polymorphicObjects.forEach {
                it.process()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
sealed class PolymorphicObjects {
    abstract fun process(): AnotherObject?
}

data class PolyMorphicObjectsInheriting1(
    //some fields
) : PolymorphicObjects() {
    override fun process(): AnotherObject? {
        //some code #1
    }
}
 
data class PolyMorphicObjectsInheriting2(
    //some other fields
) : PolymorphicObjects() {
    override fun process(): AnotherObject? {
        //some code #2
    }
}
 
data class PolyMorphicObjectsInheriting3(
    //some other fields yet again
) : PolymorphicObjects() {
    override fun process(): AnotherObject? {
        //some code #3
    }
}
```

I only want PolyMorphicObjectsInheriting1::process to be able to access this value and not the others, what is the simplest way to do it?

tldr: How to pass down value to function without adding another parameter to it?

Comment: There might be a design issue here, but it's hard to help on a hypothetical situation without your real-life use case.
It seems that your value isn't considered "possibly" useful in general for `process()` of any `PolymorphicObjects`, and that's probably why you don't want to make it a parameter of `process()`.

In that case, I believe the value should be known by the polymorphic object itself, and one way to do that would be to give it to the object at creation time. Who creates these instances?

Comment: I believe it would be best to redesign this part of system but I can't do it yet because of time constraints. List of Polymorphic objects is created by other part of system and it would also be hard to modify them because only one PolyMorphicObjectsInheriting needs it. It would be best if I could access Spring stuff (like @Value annotation) in non Spring object without additional fuss but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: You can also try ```@Configuration``` & ```@ConfigurationProperties```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's design issue but you can create public static variable in ServiceClass and set it in @PostConstruct annotated method to be equal to someValue and call on in prcoess(..) method